# Punch Board Pick 3 Probability

Tags: probability

I have a punch board with 20 places to punch and these are filled with the below options, with the rule that the player gets to punch the board until they find 3 of the same value. What would be the probability of each option? There are 20 spaces filled with 1 of each of the 5 value options. The number on the left is the number of spaces with those values. They choose spaces until 3 of the same value are chosen. I am wanting to know what the probability is that the winning value will be for each of those 4 options. I would love to know how to get to that answer myself in case we change the number of each value in the future or even the number of value options.

3 spots-$1,000

3 spots-$750

3 spots-$300

5 spots-$250

6 spots-$150

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit of what you've tried so far?

Comment: I can't get the math right on it. Someone helped me before with the formula below but we have since changed the prize structure and I can't get it to match up.

Comment: You have {a⋅V1,b⋅V2,c⋅V3,d⋅V4}where a,b,c,d  are multiplicities and V1,V2,V3,V4 are the punches representing different prizes. Suppose we are going for 3 of V1 before we get three of any other. We can win in 3 punches: 
(a3)/(a+b+c+d3)